# Will partitioning fix my deadlock issues

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-partitioning

I have an application that updates a table in my SQL Server 2005 database.  The app has one thread for each of my regions and these threads run concurrently.

On rare occasions, I run into a SQL Server deadlock error when updating the table.

It has recently occurred to me that I should partition my table by region.  It seems to me that the problem should go away but I can't replicate this error in my test environment so I can't prove it.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please post the update code / procedure.  Then we can fix the deadlock problem.  Random theories about possible fixes... can't help there.  Remember, deadlock just means a process ran to long and was killed.  It does not always mean there was a deadlock in the technical meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to dig into what was being locked and why - did the locks escalate from a row lock to a page / table lock, or was this a deadlock between row locks.

It sounds from the regionality that lock escalation may be at play in some way, the inference from your post is that you do not expect 2 threads to ever touch the same records - but that does not stop them from editing the same data page / table.

As far as SQL Server 2005 is concerned, the lock escalation is from row -> page -> table. Only in SQL Server 2008 did partition locks get placed within that escalation.

You need to dig into the deadlock and capture a deadlock graph to understand more about what is hitting the deadlock. More info on the graphs at MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188246(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: You are correct that no two threads will ever update the same row.

Comment: Suspected that was the case, which is why I think lock escalation could be at play, the page is potentially being locked, and threads are clashing at that level or higher.

Answer (score 1):

If no threads will update the same row then you should use the `with rowlock` hint.  If you are already using this hint then the problem is caused by something other than a standard deadlock.  (That is something other than a deadlock is causing the code to run so slow the engine is killing the thread with the deadlock message.)

Comment: Taken from : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323630 - Using a lock hint such as ROWLOCK only alters the initial lock plan. Lock hints do not prevent lock escalation. - It might work by using it, but it's not guarenteed, depends if the deadlock comes from escalation, or the lock plan using page / table locks in the first place. There are a few misleading hint names, thats one of them :(

Comment: A very large percentage of the thread calls call a stored procedure that does an update to a single row.  A much smaller number will be calls to a stored proc that does an insert of a single row.  Should the "with rowlock" go into both stored procs?

Comment: @wcm - Yes try both procs (it can't hurt).  As Andrew points out, it might not work but it is worth a try.  Do you have joins?  This could also cause a deadlock -- if the joins don't matter (they often don't) use the nolock hint on the join -- this could also solve the problem.  If you post the SPs I could see if they matter or not and be more helpful.